# How to backup App's data on Android over the cloud?

Tags: android, backup, android-backup-service, backup-agent

### Background

I wish to store and restore some settings and other values for an app i'm working on.

### The problem

As it turns out, Android already has a nice feature called "[BackupAgent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)".

However, it also seems it's not supported on all devices:

> Data backup is not guaranteed to be available on all Android-powered
>   devices

it's not an API issue (though it is supported only from 2.2), but a manufacturer/carrier issue:

> The backup transport is the client-side component of Android's backup
>   framework, which is customizable by the device manufacturer and
>   service provider. The backup transport may differ from device to
>   device and which backup transport is available on any given device is
>   transparent to your application. The Backup Manager APIs isolate your
>   application from the actual backup transport available on a given
>   device—your application communicates with the Backup Manager through a
>   fixed set of APIs, regardless of the underlying transport.

### The question

Is there another free alternative to store & restore data on Android into the cloud?

Comment: What's wrong with SharedPreferences?

Comment: @popovitsj nothing is wrong with SharedPreferences. However, what I'm asking for is a way to backup them (or a part of them, and/or other stuff) over the cloud, so that if the user will install the app on another device or re-install the app or performs a factory reset (or installs a new ROM), I would want to remove the need to change the settings again and again for each time he does it.

Comment: @popovitsj It doesn't persist after a factory reset/device change.

Comment: @Tonithy yes, sometimes i tend to explain too much. thank you for explaining it.